# Are these list items strings or not?

Tags: python

Edit: With the feedback from the community and re-reading the docs for enumerate I realise now that I am returning an index and value and not two values so it makes sense for 'i' to be an int.

I had this string:

```
line1 ='ewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJIH EmbT'
```

which I changed into a list:

```
line1_list = list(line1)
```

I then wanted to check for lower and upper case characters next to each other like this:

```
for i, j in enumerate(line1_list[:-1]):
   if i.islower() and j.isupper():
             print(i,j)
```

this returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'islower'
```

I didnt understand why it was saying the items in the list were ints so then I did this:

```
>>> type(line1_list[0])
<type 'str'>
>>> type(line1_list[0]) == str()
False
```

I am confused....

Comment: have you checked what `enumerate` does? you should.

Comment: See [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: `enumerate` will return index and the list element. So, in your case `i` is integer. Also you can check type as `type(line1_list[0]) is str`

Comment: You use `enumerate` so `i` is an int and `j` is a str with `line1_list[i] == j`.

Comment: `type(line1_list[0]) == str` else you're comparing a type to a string.

Comment: I see: you want `for i, j in zip(line1_list,line1_list[:-1]):`

Comment: I stand corrected: `for i, j in zip(line1[1:],line1):` (no need to convert to list), but "next to each other" misses a condition  (upper then lower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when iterated upon, `enumerate` returns a tuple (index,value) of your collection, so obviously some confusion here.

Another nice way to do that without indexes is with `zip` and slicing, and covers the case when upper follows lower AND lower follows upper (which isn't handled in your attempt)

```
line1 ='ewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJIH EmbT'
for i, j in zip(line1[1:],line1):
   if (i.islower() and j.isupper()) or (i.isupper() and j.islower()):
    print(i,j)
```

(note: no need to convert string to lists, strings can be iterated as-is)

Aside: `type(line1_list[0]) == str()` cannot work, since `str()` is the empty string, not the string class. Do `isinstance(line1_list[0],str)` instead.

Comment: thanks, all clear now!

Answer (score 1):

In you code `i` is the index and `j` is the actual character. You can loop through the list as

```
for i  in range(0,len(line1)-1):
   if line1[i].islower() and line1[i+1].isupper():
       print(line1[i], line1[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate function when you want to process index as well as the element at that index.
In this case, i will be having index and j will be having the element at that index.

what you can do here is:

```
line1_list = list(line1)
i = 0
while(i < len(line1_list)-1):
    if ((line1_list[i].islower() and line1_list[i+1].isupper()) or (line1_list[i].isupper() and line1_list[i+1].islower())):
        print line1_list[i]
        print line1_list[i+1]
    i=i+1
```

Hope this helps.